# Pgfplots Load Time

Tags: pgfplots

I got a warning in a intro to Pgfplots that It takes long time to load functions. 
I am new to Pgfplots. I am looking for package to draw graph of functions for my high school students. Now I am using Geogebra and put it as PNG in my Latex. 
I try to learn and use Pgfplots and it seems to take time to load or I may have mad mistakes.
1. Is it true that Pgfplots take time to load? I can only use XeTex for my Khmer language.
2. Is there any other package to sketch graph of function easier?

Thanks.

Comment: Just loading shouldn't take that long on a modern PC. On my notebook the following `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{pgfplots}\begin{document}\end{document}` does take around 0.35s to compile. Plotting with it can take some time (not too much though), depending on how detailed you want to get and how many points you plot.

Comment: What's the actual warning? What's the size of the data set